# How to pass too many inputs to child components in Angular 2+. Passing too many inputs to child component using @Input may slow down the performance?

Tags: angular, input

For a while I've these 3 fields but in future I may need to pass complete Associate object. Likewise If I've many more objects coming in picture for future then how to pass this data to child component. Can it make our performance slow.

<child-component [firstName]="firstName" [lastName]="lastName" [siblings]="siblings">

Comment: create the single object of your passing data.

Comment: So, are you sure passing data like in my example one by one is going to slow down the performance ? Passing one Object having all data points is going to resolve this issue ?

Comment: I am not sure about the performance but it will be easy pass the data using Object.

Comment: It may negligibly slow your app down over time, if you had thousands of these components on the DOM at the same time. Otherwise... it wouldn't be that big of deal for just a few dozen components like this. Bindings are fast in Angular. Especially inputs.

Comment: That's correct. But my question was more towards performance improvement. Let's do some research together !! Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing many objects won't slown down the performance rather than using a single object.
I would advice you to create @Input to fit the child component needs and not the parent original format.

The child component shouldn't care to know if the *firstName* comes from a *User* or an *Address* object and your child component code will be easier to read if you stick with the data you really need.

For performance purpose, a good practice is to add *OnPush* changeDetection strategy on the child component so the change detection will only be triggered if one the the inputs changes.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```